# Trouble with aligning the div's

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have this container div whose width I would like to set according to the widths of the inner divs. The issue I am facing is that the container div with auto width spans the entire page.

I have done a rough mock of what I would like (2nd implementation with constant width set) vs what I am getting with my auto settings.
http://jsfiddle.net/n3Q3n/1/

What do I do to get the div in the center without actually having to specify a width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change display on all divs and remove the floats from left and right.

on all:
    display:inline-block;
on container:
    width:100%

or this

http://jsfiddle.net/n3Q3n/15/

Comment: Not helping, that puts all the divs on the same line.

Comment: sure.  Are you wrapping the container in a fixed width bigger container by any chance?  like 960px or something?

Answer (score 0):

please try this, its working well for me, hope it will resolve your issue:

add a property in following class

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

from class **.left & .right**

**remove** `{float:left & float:right}` respectively and

**add** 
`{display:inline-block}`